# How to determine what is imported via `from m import *`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm doing some patching of import statements, and I need to know exactly what members are imported by `from m import *`. The documentation seems to indicate that when `__all__` is absent, all members will be imported that do not begin with an underscore. Is this exactly correct under all circumstances? I know that `inspect.getmembers()`, `dir()`, and `m.__dict__` all have slightly different logic, so I'm not completely sure which (if any) will provide the same list as `import *`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules "This imports all names except those beginning with an underscore (_). Note that in general the practice of importing * from a module or package is frowned upon, since it often causes poorly readable code. However, it is okay to use it to save typing in interactive sessions."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at what that `from m import *` statement does:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('from m import *', '<module>', 'single'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('*',))
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (m)
              6 IMPORT_STAR
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The key here is that it actually invokes a dedicated opcode `IMPORT_STAR`, and this is implementation specific to the interpreter that will execute this code.  This operator was originally specified in [PEP-0221](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/#implementation-details) but the implementation details specified is in the comments introduced by [this specific commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/18385172fac0).

In CPython, this is found in [`/Python/ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Python/ceval.c#L2609) (Python 3.7.2) and it in turns call [`import_all_from`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Python/ceval.c#L4861) which shows the general logic on what that actually does inside the bytecode interpreter.

In PyPy, this is found in [`/pypy/interpreter/pyopcode.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/fb40f7a5524c77b80e6c468e087d621610137261/pypy/interpreter/pyopcode.py?at=release-pypy3.6-v7.0.0&fileviewer=file-view-default#pyopcode.py-1081), and again much like the C implementation it invokes the [`import_all_from`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/fb40f7a5524c77b80e6c468e087d621610137261/pypy/interpreter/pyopcode.py?at=release-pypy3.6-v7.0.0&fileviewer=file-view-default#pyopcode.py-2095) function defined in RPython, which again has a similar logic but in a more familiar syntax for Python programmers.

In both the CPython and pypy implementation, if `__all__` is presented as a list of names inside the imported module, all matching assignments will be added to the current local scope, including those names that are prefixed with an underscore (`_`).  Otherwise, every assignment inside the module that do *not* start with an underscore will be added to the current local scope.

Comment: The key point seems to be that if `__all__` does not exist, then it grabs the keys from `m.__dict__` and calls `getattr()`. This is different from `getmembers()` or `dir()`, and even subtly different from `m.__dict__.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the following function to get a list of names and calling `getattr(m, name)` on each name:

```py
def public_members(module):
    try:
        return module.__all__  # If not iterable, imports will break.
    except AttributeError:
        return [name for name in dir(module) if not name.startswith('_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the hackiest thing you'll see all day, but it might do the trick.

```
bound = globals().copy()
from module import *
for k, v in list( globals().items() ):
    if k not in bound or bound[ k ] != v:
        print( 'new', repr( k ), repr( v ) )
```